# Избавиться от неявного преобразования

Tags: c#

Я пытался написать код по этой формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public static Complex reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)
       {          
           NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
           return (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Cos(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T))), 0, T) + Complex.ImaginaryOne * (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Sin(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T))), 0, T);              
        }
```

Хочу по методу reverstrans построить график но ругается на неявное преобразование Complex и double

```
 PointPairList list = new PointPairList();

            for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag)
            {
                 double angularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * fr;
                list.Add(angularFrequency, reverstrans(U, anguarFrequency, T));       
            }
```

Comment: А, собственно, какую точку вы туда добавить хотите? На графике должны быть комплексные кочки с осями I и R?

Comment: Вот ещё что странно. Вы добавляете точку `(fr, reverstrans(U,anguarFrequency,T))`, т.е. типа `(x,y)`, если я правильно понял. При этом у вас `y` от `x` не зависит (`fr` не является аргументом `reverstrans`). Зачем вам вообще тогда в цикле вызывать `reverstrans`?

Comment: Точка одна это спектральная плотность амплитуд,которая в свою же очередь  модуль комплексного числа(спектральной плотности)

То есть точка одна,1-ая координата это частота которая прописывается в цикле.

С помощью метода reverstrans я получаю определённое значение,которое мне нужно поместить на график.

Но оно у меня комплексное и возникла проблема как же обойти неявное преобразование и поместить на график,чтобы я увидел что там строится.

Comment: В цикле вызываю 'reverstrans' потому что на каждом шаге fr будет разное значение иными словами на каждом шаге я вычисляю обратное преобразование Фурье

На каждом шаге я беру точку спектральной плотности амплитуд и подставляю в reverstrans-обратное преобразование Фурье.

По поводу fr я ещё экспериментирую,тут уже будет зависить какой график у меня получится.
Главное узнать,что у меня там нарисовалось

Поэтому всё в цикле

Comment: Если нужен график комплексной функции `z(x)` в осях `(x,y)`, то, если не ошибаюсь, обычно берут либо реальную часть (`Re(z)`), либо модуль (`|z|`), в зависимости от физического смысла.

Comment: @beginner , вы формулу не правильно реализовали. И какой график Вы хотите получить? Зависимость чего от чего ?

Comment: Я обновил тему

Вот этот график спектральной плотности амплитуд нужно сделать с помощью обратного преобразования в другой график

Как сказали при уточнении задания нужно взять частоту и подставить в формулу
В моём случае это точка из метода GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude и после подстановки нужно решать её с помощи формулы обратного преобразования Фурье.

И поэтому я решил применить ваш образец но для обратного преобразования

Comment: **И снова у вас в программе написано не то же самое что и в формуле!**

Comment: Программный код подредактировал но увы результат такой же

Comment: @beginner почему вы интегрируете от 0 до T - когда в формуле пределы совсем другие?..

Comment: С помощью прямого преобразования Фурье получился 1-ый график(в формуле в пределах интегрирования было от 0 до Тау).

Следовательно обратное преобразование - это когда я первый график должен частично вернуть к исходному с небольшими изменениями(см. 2-ой график).

Если я прямое делал с пределами от 0 до Тау,то думаю и обратное  я тоже должен делать от 0 до Тау(период)

То что бесконечности в интегрировании(я это писал для математического форума чтобы они проверили синтаксис),синтаксис формулы одобрили.

Comment: @beginner нет, вы ошибаетесь, там бесконечности стоят не случайно. Впрочем, вы можете ограничиться какими-то пределами, потому что высокие частоты на форму сигнала влияют незначительно.

Comment: *"С помощью прямого преобразования Фурье получился 1-ый график(в формуле в пределах интегрирования было от 0 до Тау)."* - неверно. Прямое преобразование Фурье должно было вам дать **два** графика!

Comment: Зачем вы отредактировали вопрос после получения ответа на него? Нехорошо так делать.

Comment: Создал новый вопрос,а этот вопрос вернул к первоначальному варианту.и отметил что ответ получен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема - в том, что вы не понимаете ту формулу, которую используете.

**U(w) - это комплексная функция!** Вы не можете так просто заменить ее модулем и подставить в свой интеграл.

[image]

Картинка выше - это лишь график амплитуды спектральной плотности. Для восстановления формы сигнала вам нужна, помимо амплитуды, еще и фаза.

При этом функция U(w) является четной (всегда) - а потому мнимая часть u(t) уйдет в ноль (математически), останется только действительная. Ее-то и надо рисовать. Мнимую же часть u(t) можно использовать чтобы оценить точность интегрирования.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста как это должно произойти или выглядеть.


Мои действия(Мой Алгоритм)
Я нашёл спектральную плотность амплитуд,нашёл спектральную плотность
-Нахожу фазу
-Потом фазу подставляю в формулу обратного преобразования Фурье и потом уже получаю новую комплексную функцию.

Затем я должен из метода изъять действительное число и уже его добавлять в построение графика?

Comment: @beginner идите учить математику

Comment: Может просто ответить на мой вопрос.

Я же не прошу написать мне код

А как чтобы взять и просто ответить.
Правильно я написал алгоритм или нет?Опять же я с ваших же слов его написал и спросил так или нет?

Я бы её выучил если бы была нормальная теория с примерами обратного преобразования Фурье.

Я её выучу,как сдам этот проект и я забуду про этот сайт,так как будет реальная работа.

Comment: @beginner вы написали какой-то бред про фазу. Где вы в формуле обратного преобразования Фурье видели фазу отдельно? Она там только в составе U(w)