# Нахождение фазы.Неявное преобразование типа "void" в "double" невозможно

Tags: c#

Чтобы не засорять этот вопрос и не нарушать правила и тематику,создаю новый

Начало отсюда [Избавиться от неявного преобразования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529092/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment660055_529092)

Было сказано
Для восстановления формы сигнала вам нужна, помимо амплитуды, еще и фаза(c)Pavel_Mayorov

Мой примерный АЛГОРИТМ

Я в коллекцию загружаю все свои комплексные функции.

Затем с помощью ForEach я хочу разделить на части,а именно Imaginary и Real и сразу же получить арктангенс.

Руководствуюсь этой формулой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тем самым я получаю фазу(Согласно теории)
Реализую это всё в коде.

```
public static double getfaza(int frc, int frc1, double T, double U)
        {
            int frequency, counter;
            List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
            for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
            {
                values.Add(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T));
            }  
            return values.ForEach(x1 => Math.Atan(x1.Real/x1.Imaginary));
        }
```

Подставляю полученную фазу в формулу обратного преобразования Фурье.0 и Тау я оставил как пределы интегрирования чтобы потом посмотреть на изменение результатов.

```
public static Complex reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T,int frc,int frc1)
         {
         NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
         if (anguarFrequency == 0)// Учитываем деление на 0
            return new Complex(U * T, 0);
         return (1 / 2 * Math.PI) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Cos(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency, T)) * getfaza(frc, frc1, T, U)), 0, T) + Complex.ImaginaryOne * (1 / 2 * Math.PI) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Sin(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency, T)) * getfaza(frc, frc1, T, U)), 0, T);
        }
```

Вот это пока в теории не могу найти.

При этом функция U(w) является четной (всегда) - а потому мнимая часть u(t) уйдет в ноль (математически), останется только действительная. Ее-то и надо рисовать. Мнимую же часть u(t) можно использовать чтобы оценить точность интегрирования(с)Pavel_Mayorov

Текущие проблемы

```
return values.ForEach(x1 => Math.Atan(x1.Real/x1.Imaginary));-Неявное преобразование типа "void" в "double" невозможно
```

Вот здесь я в тупике.
Как видно меня там void нету,коллекция `values` объявлена как Complex,все действия над ней я провожу как над комплексным числом.
`values.ForEach` я применяю чтобы из каждого комплексного получить фазу

И опять она(но если я решу 1-ую формулу,думаю 2-ая исчезнет)

```
list.Add(angularFrequency, reverstrans(U, anguarFrequency, T,frc,frc1));  - Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно
```

UPD:

К сожалению я с Select только начинаю знакомится и знакомство пока неудачное.

```
public static double getfaza(int frc, int frc1, double T, double U)
        {
            int frequency, counter;
            List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
            for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
            {
                values.Add(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T));
            }
            return values.Select((value,x1) => new {Math.Atan(x1.Real/x1.Imaginary)});
        }
```

`new {Math.Atan(x1.Real/x1.Imaginary)}`-Неверное определение члена анонимного типа. Члены анонимного типа должны быть объявлены присваиванием члена, простым именем или доступом к члену.

Прошу не минусовать.
Мне реально хочется быстро с этим разобраться,сделать и всё.И учить другие интересные разделы в программировании.

Comment: Кстати, `(1 / 2 * Math.PI)` равно 0. Правильно `(1/2π)` будет `(1 / (2 * Math.PI))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код пытается вернуть наружу результат выполнения ForEach. Проблема в том, что ForEach ничего не возвращает. Он пробегает по коллекции, вызывает функцию для каждого элемента, а результат - выбрасывает. Это аналог цикла foreach.

Метод, который пробегает по коллекции, и делает из нее новую коллекцию называется Select. Используйте его вместо ForEach.

Comment: скорее всего тут надо оставить ForEach, а после него вернуть values

Comment: @grundy я если честно не совсем представляю что там происходит. Но оставлять там for each смысла нет - он же не меняет ничего.

Comment: А, это я, значит, тоже плохо посмотрел :) мне показалось, что, как раз, меняет

Comment: К сожалению этой мой наверное 1-ый опыт с Select.
Он позволяет формулы вычислять и запоминать полученное?
Я обновил код

Comment: @beginner  Вы пытаетесь писать код наугад? К сожалению, это просто напрасная трата времени. Под используйте Select вместо ForEach я имел ввиду именно замену имени метода. Зачем вы дописали new {}? И даже после этого - вы получите на выходе селекта последовательность (несколько) double. Метод getfaza должен вернуть один из них? Среднее? Сумму?