# Обратное преобразование Фурье,преобразование между Complex и double

Tags: c#

Продолжение этого вопроса [Избавиться от неявного преобразования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529092/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

После указанных мне замечаний,прочитал теорию и на основе прочитанной теории изменил свой код

Вот источник откуда я взял формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так у меня есть U(jw)-она у меня в методе `GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T))`

Что мной было сделано

На основе прочитанной теории я понял что нужно получить величины U'(w) и U''(w)
Я добавил в код поля,которые их получают и сделал вычисление как на формуле 4.10 из теории

то есть отнял U'(w) от U''(w)
И полученные значения планировал уже подставить в формулу.
Никакой фазы,как мне указали раньше я отдельно не нахожу,всё как я понял находится в найденном значении `ValFurieTrans`

Теперь собственно к программной реализации
Проблем состоит в синтаксисе формулы,возможно я её не так отображаю в коде

```
public static double reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)
       {          
           NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
           Complex u1 = U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(anguarFrequency), 0, T);//U'(w)
           Complex u2 = U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(anguarFrequency), 0, T);//U''(w)       
           Complex img = Complex.ImaginaryOne.Imaginary;// инициализируем новый экземпляр объекта complex samvalue(1,0)
           Complex ValFurieTrans = u1 - img * u2; //Вычисляем U(w)e^-j*fi(w)= U'(w) - U''(w) 
           return (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) *GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency, T) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * w - ValFurieTrans), 0, T) + Complex.ImaginaryOne * (1 / (2 * Math.PI))* GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency,T)* integration.Calculate(w => Math.Sin(anguarFrequency * w - ValFurieTrans), 0, T);              
        }
```

Ругается на `Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * w -ValFurieTrans)`-преобразование типа из "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно

А теперь мои попытки,которые я приводил чтобы исправить ситуацию.

Если вместо `Math.Sin,Math.Cos` я напишу `Complex.Sin,Complex.Cos` то компилятор выдаст такую ошибку

Не удается преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" в делегат "System.Func", поскольку некоторые из типов результатов, возвращаемых блоком, не могут быть неявно преобразованы в тип результата, возвращаемого делегатом

Оно и понятно ведь метод Calculate содержит Func и я не думаю что мне нужно весь класс и методы переделывать в Complex.

Я делал отдельные методы Calculate1 с типом Complex но компилятор неумолим.

А если я сделаю так

```
 return (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(ValFurieTrans)), 0, T) + Complex.ImaginaryOne * (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(w => Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(ValFurieTrans)), 0, T);              
        }
```

То компилятор это пропустит ,но возникнет другая проблема,при работе программы выскакивает исключение в верхней строке.

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidCastException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Numerics.Complex" к типу "System.IConvertible"
```

Но проблема с преобразованием из Complex в double перемещается в эту строку.
Проблема в синтаксисе.
Поэтому и появляются проблемы с преобразованием.

Comment: А каким образом вы хотите преобразовать Complex в double? Комплексная переменная содержит ведь действительную и мнимую часть.

Comment: Если в комплексном числе нету мнимой части то double VFT = ValFurieTrans.RealOne, иначе невозможно математически преобразовать. Можно найти радиус как Math.Sqrt(ValFurieTrans.RealOne^2 + ValFurieTrans.ImagineOne^2) но это не будет представление этого числа

Comment: Не помогает даже если только действительную часть выражаю к примеру VatFurieTrans.Real подставляю в формулу и всё-также ругается

Comment: Вы не должны стремиться заткнуть компилятор. Компилятор подсказывает вам, что у вас что-то не в порядке с программой. Вы должны понять **смысл** операций, которые вы выполняете. **Чем должно быть значение `ValFurieTrans`?** Если комплексным числом, почему вы пытаетесь присвоить его переменной типа `double`?

Comment: Значение ValFurieTrans - это спектральная плотность фаз фи(омега) я её получаю путём вычисления U'(w)-j*U''(w) И то и другое комплексные числа Проблема в том что Math.Cos() не принимает эти значения,а изменить на Complex.Cos не решает моей проблемы,так как рушится решение интегралов методом трапеции(Calculate) 


Смысл операций вычисления переменных u1,u2 это нахождение U'(w) и U''(w) чтобы потом получить значение ValFurieTrans.

Я понимаю что проблема в синтаксисе формулы,которую я запрограммировал на основе теории.

Comment: Отлично, это комплексное число. Значит, вы не можете никак пытаться присвоить его переменной типа `double`. Поэтому вы в принципе не можете применить к нему `Math.Cos`, который требует на вход `double`.

Comment: Если вам нужен косинус комплексного числа, пользуйтесь `Complex.Cos`, да. То, что при этом что-то другое не работает, проблема не вычисления косинуса, а того кода, который не работает. `Math.Cos` работать в этой точке **в принципе не сможет**. Точно так же, как он не сможет посчитать косинус строки или даты.